# jQuery display object value

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to access some info in my database and displaying the result of my query in some textboxes.. my code works but it says object object..

here's my jQuery code:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.update_button', function() {

    var manufacturer_part = jQuery(this).val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/codes/clearhouse_processor.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {update_key: manufacturer_part},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {

            jQuery('#update-manufacturer-part').val(result.part_number);
            jQuery('#update-manufacturer').val(result.manufacturer);

            jQuery('.update-form').stop();
            jQuery('.update-form').slideToggle('slow');
            jQuery('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery('.update-form').offset().top-60
            }, 750);


        }
    });

});
```

and here's my php code...

```
if(isset($_POST['update_key'])){

    $manufacturer_part = $_POST['update_key'];

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
    // Order it by the ordering field.
    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('part_number')));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('clearing_house'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('part_number') . '='.preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", @$manufacturer_part) );

    // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
    $db->setQuery($query);

    // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    echo json_encode($results);

}
```

and btw, I am using joomla here...

thanks in advance,

Comment: hello @H0WARD still can't get the result.

Comment: `var_dump(results)` , show us the What does `results` looks like.

Comment: and `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` to dump the result on browser's console too.

Comment: here is the result of console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); `[{"part_number":"235633778762"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 jQuery('#update-manufacturer-part').val(result[0].part_number);
```

it is receiving an array from the server

by the result you gave

and if you want to see all the results that you receive

jQuery('#update-manufacturer-part').val(result[0].part_number);

```
_.map(result,function(){return part_number; }).join(",")
```

on the query itself update the fields that you need to get

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('part_number', 'manufacturer', 'field3', 'fieild4')));
```

Comment: it says undefined.. when I tried to alert(result.part_number)

Comment: try to see the  alert(result.part_number.length)

Comment: still cannot sir.. I alert the result and it displays `object Object`

Comment: so if alert(result.part_number) is an object that means it does not have length. try to alert (JSON.stringify(result.part_number))
or jQuery('#update-manufacturer-part').val(JSON.stringify(result.part_number));

Comment: just give the result of the JSON.stringify(result) it will be enough to solve that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80119/discussion-between-dan-kuida-and-user3113490).